# What is the default value for a String in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the default value for a `String` in Dart.

It must be either '' or `null`.

```
String myString;
print(myString);
print(myString=='');
print(myString==null);
```

What will this return ?

Comment: what stops you from running it by yourself?

Comment: a fine point - and I will run it myself - I just thought I could google for it and save myself a test run - and as I couldn't find that answer right away I thought I'd create it out there - I'll be posting an answer to this in just a moment

Comment: if you want to make a quick run use https://dartpad.dartlang.org/

Comment: I didn't know about that - that's great thank you!

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the official documentation:

> Uninitialized variables have an initial value of null.
> Even variables with numeric types are initially null because numbers—like everything else in Dart—are objects.

```
String lineCount;
assert(lineCount == null);
```

you can check this link https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#default-value

Answer (score 3):

#### The default value will be `null`

I actually found the answer here : 
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#default-value

> Uninitialized variables have an initial value of null.

And thanks to @pskink and dartpad.dartlang.org, I was also able to run this without having to wait for the iOS build to complete, and the result of code is :

```
null   // from print(myString);
false  // from print(myString=='');
true   // print(myString==null);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default In dart lang string value is null.

```
String myString;
print(myString);
```

**Result**

```
null
```